# Move and align subplots to match a specific layout

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an nxn matrix that I want to plot, and I also want to plot the sum of rows and cols.

So I have this:

```
data = np.random.randn(5, 5)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axes[0, 0].imshow(data)
axes[0, 1].imshow(data.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1))
axes[1, 0].imshow(data.sum(axis=0).reshape(1, -1))
```

[image]

How can I align the row and column to the main image and put them closer to it?
I would also like to get rid of the empty axis in the bottom right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
data = np.random.randn(5, 5)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2,
                         gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [5, 1],
                                      'width_ratios': [5, 1]
                                     }
                        )
axes[0, 0].imshow(data)
axes[0, 1].imshow(data.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1))
axes[1, 0].imshow(data.sum(axis=0).reshape(1, -1))
axes[1, 1].set_visible(False)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Definitely a good start, thank you sir.